# How to set the print statement A5 format?

Tags: php, printing

when I pressed the print button. I would like to Print statement in A5 format. Two identical printing statement side by side on one A4 page in landscape in php and using table for forms. is it possible? or any other method are there?

Comment: the only way to get total layout control for printing is to convert to pdf.

Answer (score 1):

To determine the page size (which by default will probably be A4 or Letter), you can use the [`size`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#page-size-prop) property:

```
@page {
  size: A5;
}
```

Apart from specialized user agents such as [Prince XML](http://princexml.com/doc/7.0/page-size/), browser support is low though. What you can do is emmiting two copies of the table to print, and styling them:

```
#container2 {display: none;}
@media print {
   #container2 {display: block;}
   #container1, #container2 {width: 40%; float: left; ...}
}
```